# add input field on bo order table in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i am new to prestashop 
i am trying to add new input field for update weight of order 
can anyone help me to know how to add input field in Back Office order table[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZDLE.png)

Answer (score 0):

i myself add that field.
by overriding
helper/list/list_content.tpl
and 
helper/list/list_header.tpl
file
and adding extra column in it
after that make ajax call for updation of data[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLRtN.png)